# jquery convert serialized form inputs to xml string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all my form inputs and then create with them an xml string containing there values in order to send them via ajax.

i want this :

```
<form id="formtest">
 <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1"/>
 <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2"/>
 <input type="text" name="test3" id="test3"/>
 <input type="text" name="test4" id="test4"/>
 <input type="text" name="test5" id="test5"/>           
</form>
```

to become:

```
<formtest>
  <test1></test1>
  <test2></test2>
  <test3></test3>
  <test4></test4>
  <test5></test5>
</formtest>
```

How can this be done?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: I want to get all inputs and serialize them in xml shape and send them in ajax , with xml string as a parameter.

Comment: @user590586 Please show us the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

First, create your XML document within jQuery:

```
var xml = $('<xmlBody></xmlBody>'); //<xmlBody> can be replaced with whatever tag is appropriate for your uses
```

Add values like such:

```
xml.find('xmlBody').first().append('<tag>'+data+'</tag>');
```

You may need a plugin to serialize the XML.  [This](http://jquery.feedables.com/story/4653392/XML-to-String-convertor), perhaps?

This is a very simple example, but hopefully it will get you started.  Look around the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for more info.

Comment: @CloudedVision: thank's for your reply . but this is not what i ment.. my question is how to create the "data" inside the tags.. i want all the inputs to be shown as xml tags that inside of them their values..

Comment: Do you mean you want to serialize the jQuery XML object that you have? I edited my answer, it should cover that now.

Comment: @user590586 The answer given by @CloudedVision is perfect to do that. What issue do you see?

Comment: @Ritesh: from what i see in the attached link it creates an xml like .html() , but i want only the id of the input and it's value.

Comment: @user590586 I think you just need to replace root, tag and value in answer given by @CloudedVision. See the snippet in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var xml = $('<formtest></formtest>');

$("form#formtest input").each(function(){
    xml.find('formtest').first().append('<' + $(this).attr('id') + '>' + $(this).val() + '</' +  $(this).attr('id') + '>');
});
```