# saving form data to local drive as xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, forms

I would like to have data entered into an html form saved to my local drive. I do not want the form data sent to a server and do not want to have the saving of the form data require internet access. Is there a way to have this data saved via javascript to a local xml file? Below is an example of some basic form fields I would like to save to xml locally. thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="/my-local-drive" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13073263/